# Virtual Box error: kernel requires an x86-64 CPU

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I encounter the following error :

This kernal requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU. Unable to boot...

I am using a 64-bit machine. However, my drop-down menu in step 3 only has 32-bit versions available. Hence, I selected Ubuntu 32 bit version and was later unable to proceed, and the error showed up. Could someone please help me out here?

Thank you

Comment: You should enable virtualization on the processor from the BIOS and it will show you the 64 bit options

Comment: hi, I tried looking for this option as well, on my windows 10.. but I cannot seem to locate it. Would you have an idea as to HOW I can enable this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Reboot your computer
2. Right when the computer is coming up from the black screen,

press Delete, Esc, F1, F2, or F4.

Each computer manufacturer uses a different key but it may show a brief message at boot telling you which one to press.

If you miss it the first time, reboot and try again. It helps to tap the key about twice a second when the computer is coming up.

If you are not able to enter the BIOS via this method, consult your computer’s manual.

3. In the BIOS settings, find the configuration items related to the CPU.

These can be in under the headings Processor, Chipset, or Northbridge.

4. Enable virtualization; the setting may be called VT-x, AMD-V, SVM, or Vanderpool.

Enable Intel VT-d or AMD IOMMU if the options are available.

5. Save your changes and reboot.

[If problem persist after doing that  usually doesnt]

Delete any existing VMs (Machine > Remove ** and select ** Delete all files) and re-import the .ova file (following step 4 and subsequent steps of the installation instructions).